# How to custom sort order in django like mysql FIELD Function

Tags: mysql, django, django-forms

How to write Django queryset custom sort order like MySQL field function in Django

```
select status from company order by FIELD(status, 'Follow Up', 'Interested - Call back scheduled', 'Need to send details', 'Quotation sent')


Comapany.objects.all().order_by(?)
```

Comment: Does my snippet worked or still got problems?

Comment: @Eranki Does Syed's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use objects.extra()

```
Company.objects.extra(
    select={'manual': "FIELD(status, 'Follow Up', 'Interested - Call back scheduled', 'Need to send details', 'Quotation sent')"},
    order_by=['manual']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as follows using: `CASE`, `WHEN` and `VALUE` to achieve a similar CUSTOM SORT BY feature of MySQL

```
Company.objects.annotate(res_val=Case(When(status='Follow Up', then=Value(1)),
                                  When(status='Interested - Call back scheduled', then=Value(2)),
                                  When(status='Need to send details', then=Value(3)),
                                  When(status='Quotation sent', then=Value(4)),
                                  default=Value(5))).order_by('res_val')
```

You can change the `.order_by()` to ascending or descending based on your use case

I hope this helps you out

**Explanation of the snippet above:**

So, in this case what I have done is that I have annotated the whole query set and assigned them an integer values based on the value of *`status`* column. The value is given on the basis of which has high preference, which you can tweak as per your own needs. I think case, I have given the highest preference to status **"Follow Up"** then the preference decreases with increasing value, with random status' having the value **'5'**. Once this is done I just sort the *`res_val`* field based on the requirement (ASCENDING or DESCENDING). You can tweak the values as per your needs to achieve **"Custom Sorting"**

Comment: typo on value annotation for "Quotation sent" repeated Value(3) instead of Value(4).

Answer (score -1):

Just mention the column name inside the order_by() like shown below.

```
Comapany.objects.all().order_by('column_name')
```

The above code will give the result in ascending order.
If you want the result in descending order add -(minus) in front of the column name like shown below.

```
Comapany.objects.all().order_by('-column_name')
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Plan A: Try things, such as

```
  Comapany.objects.all().order_by("FIELD(status, 'Follow Up',
        'Interested - Call back scheduled',
        'Need to send details', 'Quotation sent')")
```

Plan B: Use Django's way of emitting raw SQL.

Plan C: Abandon the framework.

Comment: Is there a way to store those strings (Follow up, Interested....) in an array and pass that in query?

Comment: @Eranki - Will those strings change or be rearranged from query to query?

Comment: It will change. In my case those are integer list. I'm filtering data with those integer list. And at the same time I want the queried data to be in same order of those integer list.